# Changes in node_modules are disregarded. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, yarnpkg, laravel-mix

I am making a small patch in an NPM package in my code.  I made the change in the `node_modules`.  When I rebuild and reload the browser, none of the changes have perpetuated.

I am using laravel mix (a wrapper for webpack) for my js build.  I have assumed the node_module is cached somewhere and that is why the changes aren't showing.  I have tried:

- `yarn cache clean`
- `php artisan cache:clear`
- deleting `node_modules/.cache/`

No luck.

Looking at the package further, I see it has `src/` and `dist/` directories.  I made changes in `src/` but I guess the package is reading from `dist/`.  Is the `src/` folder pointless? do I have to fork/rebuild the repo? Or is there an easy way to rebuild the package from my locally patched version?

Comment: `yarn cache clean`

Comment: `yarn cache list`: shows the list of cached dependencies

Comment: `clear` was a typo, good catch